# Is there a way to return a list of all markers that are not currently within a cluster group?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm currently working on a project using angular-leaflet-directive + the leaflet markercluster plugin.

What I'm looking to do is, on a certain event (for example, +/- zoom level or when the cluster groups change) I'd like to have a function run which returns all markers that are not currently clustered.

The reason for doing this is because I'd like to have all visible markers have a circle path around it (20 nautical miles, but that's really not important)..

Does anybody have any idea if this is possible?

Thanks for the help. Please let me know what other info you might need and I'll do my best to get it to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After creating your `markerClusterGroup`, you could do something like this :

```
// Let's assume you have a global map variable that refers to the Leaflet Map
MyClusterGroup.eachLayer(function(feature) {
    // the cluster group holds all the features
    // but only the ones not clustered are added to the map
    if (map.hasLayer(feature)) {
        feature.setStyle({ // Only feature not clustered will have their style re-render
            fillColor : "red"
        });
        // Do whatever your want with this feature, you have full access to it
    }
});
```

This might not be the best stuff to do in terms of performance but I guess this will work fine for your case. Else you should sneak into the marker plug-in code and modify/extend it directly to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I just had the same problem.

My Solution was to iterate throuh my markers and check if they are in bounds. The attribute map of the marker is null if it is clustered.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if(typeof markers[i] !== "undefined"){
    if( bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition()) && markers[i].map !== null){
        console.log(markers[i])
    }
    }
}
```